# Singular Fit for Random Effect in Binomial GLMM

Tags: lme4, singular, glmm

At my wits end running models and would greatly appreciate help. I am currently running GLMM's to understand the relationships between a set of predictor variables (continuous data) and my binomial outcome variable (0,1 - 'self_reported_conflict). Ultimately, my goal is to determine what variables (or set therof) predict conflict outcomes between people and bears.

I have data about predictor/outcome variables for 201 households in my study area. I'd like to run log link function GLMMs with a random effect for 'household'. I have 194 households and 201 observations (most households have 1 observation, several have 2). However, whenever I include my random effect (household) only in my model, my fit is singular (boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular').

I can't for the life of me understand *why* this is occuring in my most basic model (random effect only). I've read other posts with similar questions but can't seem to extrapolate the reasons to my data.

Any help immensely appreciate.

I try the following code for my null model (with random effect):

```
    >m.e1 <- glmer(self_reported_conflict ~ 1 + (1|household),
              data = df, 
            family = binomial(link = "logit"))

    >summary(m.e1)

    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace 
    Approximation) [glmerMod]
    Family: binomial  ( logit )
    Formula: self_reported_conflict ~ 1 + (1 | household)
    Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   213.6    220.3   -104.8    209.6      201 

    Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
   -0.5184 -0.5184 -0.5184 -0.5184  1.9290 

    Random effects:
     Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
    household (Intercept) 0        0       
    Number of obs: 203, groups:  household, 194

    Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)  -1.3140     0.1718  -7.649 2.02e-14 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
    boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')'
```